# Counting business days between subsequent pandas dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have large pandas dataframe (more than 1000000 rows) where I need to get in the fastest way possible the number of business days (excluding weekends) between two rows (n and n+1) where each contains a column date. And each time, I need to store the duration (outcome) in the row  n of the same dataframe in a column called 'duration'. The result is in seconds.

I am using the below code to do the calculation in the fastest way I know about (any better way is welcomed ;-) ).

```
    tmp_df['duration'] = 
    tmp_df['origin_tick_generation_time_stamp'].shift(-1) - tmp_df[
            'origin_tick_generation_time_stamp']
```

I would like to calculate the duration without weekends in my code. I read that np.busday_count(date1, date2) will do exactly that. But do not know how to use it in my case.
Is there a way to do it?

Many thanks

Comment: You have 1 million dates?

Comment: I have much more. These are not just dates. each row has a date for an operation and I am computing the duration between 2 operations. An operation is an activity on a transaction in a bank. And I need the duration in business days.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas.Series.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
tmp_df['duration'] = tmp_df['origin_tick_generation_time_stamp'].diff(-1)*-1
```

or

```
tmp_df['duration'] = tmp_df['origin_tick_generation_time_stamp'].diff()*shift(-1)
```

it's something faster.

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['a']=np.arange(1000000)
import time
```

---

```
start_time = time.time()
df['a'].shift(-1)-df['a']
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print(elapsed_time)


#0.023838520050048828
```

---

```
start_time = time.time()
df['a'].diff(-1)*-1
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print(elapsed_time)
#0.008615493774414062
```

---

```
start_time = time.time()
df['a'].diff().shift(-1)
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print(elapsed_time)
#0.011868000030517578
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. Would you know how to get with this way of programming the differences between two rows as business days and not full calendar days?